# How to move to audio file with matching text

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, nlp, google-cloud-platform

I have an audio file which is converted into text by google speech API. I want a new feature like while clicking on the text at the same time audio timing should move to match a place in an audio file?

Please refer this(http://www.ted.com/talks/reed_hastings_how_netflix_changed_entertainment_and_where_it_s_headed/transcript#t-128497)

Comment: SO is not a free coding service. You want that feature, get to work.

Comment: Is there any other tools are available for that?Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: Questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic for SO - see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

Time offset values can be included in your speech recognition results [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/basics#time-offsets). By setting the `enable_word_time_offsets` parameter to `True` in your request configuration, timestamps will be included for the first alternative provided in the recognition response [[2]](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/async-time-offsets#speech-async-recognize-gcs-python).